# Mule: Accessing a value given an Array of Arrays

Tags: mule

I am trying to access the value of every 2nd element in every subarray of an Array of arrays in mule. For example here is my payload (stored in flowVar).

InputPayload=[[JAAW, 3000.0, EQtEAM], [JAAW, 233333.0, 3EAM]]

I am trying to access the second element of each array in an iteration , so I do the following:

```
      <foreach collection="#[flowVars.InputPayload]" counterVariableName="i" doc:name="For Each" > 
      <set-variable variableName="ID" value="#[flowVars.InputPayload[i][2]]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

However my code breaks with the following error:

---

Message               : Execution of the expression "flowVars.InputPayload[i][2]" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: ArrayList,

how can I access the value of every second element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the error is caused by incorrect index assigment, `#[flowVars.InputPayload[i][2]]` (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException). the index is started from 1, error occurs during the second iteration.

IMHO there are two options to solve the issue:

1. Subtract the index with 1: `#[flowVars.InputPayload[i - 1][2]]`
2. Modify the expression, to directly use **payload**. Since the payload inside the *For Each* scope is already refers to the iterated item itself: `#[payload[2]]`

Answer (score 0):

Was not reading off the payload, that was the problem